# Is there a way to have @Alternate class for an interceptor class implementing ContainerRequestFilter annotated with @Provider in Quarkus?

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, quarkus-testing

In Quarkus:
There is class implementing ContainerRequestFilter annotated with @Provider like below:

```java
@Provider
public class RequestInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        //work with context 
    }
}
```

Now while executing a unit test class which is annotated with @QuarkusTest, I want to spy/mock this interceptor annotated with @Provider, to check the context.

Note: All the test cases are written using rest assured to make a call to the endpoint

I tried creating spy/mock for the RequestInterceptor class but failed stating that it is not eligible for mocking/spy.

So as next approach, tried creating a RequestTestInterceptor.class in test package as below

```java
@Provider
@AlternativePriority(1)
public class RequestTestInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        //work with context 
    }
}
```

But in this case, both RequestInterceptor and RequestTestInterceptor were executed for a test case.

How to mock/spy/create an alternate class for @Provider in Quarkus?

Comment: Have you tried using `@InjectMock RequestTestInterceptor interceptor` in your test?

Comment: Yes, I tried `@InjectMock` and `@InjectSpy` as well. Getting the following exception -- Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.config.http.RequestInterceptor@21d3d6ec is not a normal scoped CDI bean, make sure the bean is a normal scope like `@ApplicationScoped` or `@RequestScoped`

Comment: I was unable to edit the above comment, so here is the exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException --  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.config.http.RequestInterceptor@21d3d6ec is not a normal scoped CDI bean, make sure the bean is a normal scope like `@ApplicationScoped` or `@RequestScoped`

Comment: Try adding `@MockitoConfig(convertScopes = true)` as well